# When parsing Atom XML feeds, how should conflicting CDATA and entity escaped elements be handled?

Tags: xml, feed, cdata, atom-feed, xml-encoding

How should an Atom feed parser handle the following line of XML in a feed:

```
<title type="html"><![CDATA[Johnson &amp; Johnson]]></title>
```

For the sake of the discussion, lets assume that the originally intended text was in fact `Johnson & Johnson`.  I came across this [online discussion](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9992) about this issue and there seemed to be 2 different opinions:

1.
 [Opinion #1 - claims that this content is double-encoded](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9992#comment:16).  The text "Johnson & Johnson" text has been entity escaped and then encoded again by being wrapped in a CDATA section.  He states that a well behaved xml parser will return `Johnson &amp; Johnson`, because this is how the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sec) states CDATA encoded data should be handled.

2. [Opinion #2 - claims that the Atom spec takes precedent](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9992#comment:18).  He states that the CDATA acts as a passthrough. `Johnson &amp; Johnson` comes out as `Johnson &amp; Johnson`. If this were just an XML document, it would end there. However, because it is Atom, we must then look at the [Atom spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-3.1.1.2) to determine the proper behavior.  The atom spec states that any element with the `type="html"` contains entity escaped html.  Therefore, we should be free to decode it.

Which of these factually correct?   Should a proper Atom XML parser produce:
`Johnson & Johnson` or `Johnson &amp; Johnson` given this particular situation?

Answer (score 1):

Both opinions are correct:

- The title encoded as text is `Johnson & Johnson`.
- The title encoded as HTML is `Johnson &amp; Johnson`
- The title encoded as HTML in XML is `<![CDATA[Johnson &amp; Johnson]]>`

Answer (score 0):

CDATA is character data - completely ignored by the parser between `<![CDATA` and `]>`. It has to be since xml cannot handle `&amp;`. Therefore, there is no "double encoding" - any parser skips to the close tag, ignoring anything in between. I've not come across a parser that allows actual nesting (embedded full CDATA open and close tags).

Answer (score 0):

Content between CDATA markers is not parsed for entities of tags, so the parsed value of the text node is `Johnson &amp; Johnson`.

Note that the attribute says `type="html"`, so it should then be parsed as HTML.

e.g. If you were expressing this as a webpage you might write:

```
<h1>Johnson &amp; Johnson</h1>
```

If it had said `type="text"` then you would have needed to encode the plain text as HTML which would have given you:

```
<h1>Johnson &amp;amp; Johnson</h1>
```

Comment: Your statement "so it should then be parsed as HTML" is where the ambiguity comes in for me.  If the Atom library, typically for `type="html"` elements would html-decode its element's text if there was no CDATA, are you stating that it also should html-decode the element text that is wrapped in a CDATA?

Comment: *If the Atom library, typically for type="html"* — The Atom library shouldn't, the HTML renderer should.

Comment: Why shouldn't the feed parser libraries take it upon themselves to unescape elements marked as `type="html"` when the spec clearly states that they are escaped as such?  When you ask Python's `feedparser` library, or PHP's `Simplepie` library to return the `Title` from a feed that had it's title defined as:  `<title type="html">Example &lt;p&gt;title&lt;/p&gt;</title>`, they will all return `Example <p>title</p>`.  This question revolves around whether or not the CDATA element should circumvent that typical unescaping that they do when parsing the data into their unescaped form.

Comment: @mmcdole — In that example that HTML is just encoded using entities instead of using CDATA. So yes, CDATA should be treated as CDATA.